# Fisher information in one parameter exponential family.

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

We define the one-parameter exponential family of distribution functions as those whose pmf/pdf can be written as $$\exp\{c(\theta)T(x) + d(\theta) + s(x)\}$$
I would like to show that if c is twice differentiable with a positive derivative and $E(T(X))= \theta$
then $I(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\text{var}(T(X))}$

I tried directly computing the fisher information of theta, but I do not see why the equality holds.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Inspect the equality condition of Cramer-Rao inequality.

Comment: Are you referring to the Lehmann-Schleffe theorem?

Comment: It is asking you to prove that variance of $T$ attains the Cramer-Rao lower bound for $\theta$. For that it suffices to show that 1st derivative of log-likelihood is proportional to $T-\theta$. This is easy to show but I am not sure whether the condition $c$ is twice differentiable is used in this approach.

Comment: Could you explain why showing the proportionality is sufficient?

Comment: As I said, that follows by studying the equality condition of Cramer-Rao inequality, which is often proved using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I don't see why the condition $E(d/d\theta \log(f(x)))$ = 0 always holds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\hat{\theta}=T(x)$ is an unbiased estimate  for $\theta$, since $E[T(x)]=\theta$. The Cramer-Rao lower bound indicates that

$$\text{Var}(T(x))= \text{Var}(\hat{\theta})\geq \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$$

The equality holds if $Z = \frac{\partial \log f}{\partial \theta}$ and $\hat{\theta} = T(x)$ are linearly related.

For the exponential family density function we have:

$$Z=\frac{\partial \log f(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta}= \frac{\partial (c(\theta)T(x)+d(\theta)+s(x))}{\partial \theta} = c'(\theta)T(x)+d'(\theta) $$

which is linear and hence, the equality is achieved for exponential family distributions, which means:

$$\text{Var}(T(x))= \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$$

You may also refer to [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177706258) for the proof.

**Note**: To study the equality condition of Cramer-Rao inequality, please see the proof in this [lecture note](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/stats/stats200/stats200.1172/Lecture15.pdf). It includes a Cauchy-Schwartz inequality where:

$$\text{Cov}[Z,T]\leq \text{Var}[Z]\times \text{Var}[T]$$
with $Z=\frac{\partial log f}{\partial \theta}$ and $T = T(x)$. The equality can be achieved if $Z$ is a linear function of $T$.